# Derivative of a entire function is constant then the function is a linear poynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

If a derivative of a function is constant in a open connected set then it is a linear polynomial, the proof use the idea of connectedness. But I want a proof using that the function is entire. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is entire, then $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ and $f'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)a_{k+1}z^k$. By assumption, $(k+1)a_{k+1}=0$ for $k\ge 1$, so $f(z)=a_0+a_1z$.